# Laravel: Filtering in eloquent with optional user input

Tags: php, variables, laravel, eloquent

I have a list of news stories in my laravel website.  On the `/news/` page a quick list of stories is shown.

Now I want to allow users to filter news.  For example, only show "sports" stories.

In my controller I did this:

```
$input = Input::all();

$events = DB::table('news')
        ->where('category', '=', $input['type'])
        ->order_by('created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(10);
```

Now, this allows me to visit `/news?type=sports` and it correctly only shows news items within the sports category.  This only works if a type is given though, and will obviously fail if there is no type given.

What is the best solution to this?  I know I can check to see if `$input['type']` exists, and if it does, write a completely new, second `"$news = DB::table('news')..."` code, but I am thinking that I may actually want to have multiple user inputs, which would make that option not work.  For example, what if I want to sort by type and location?  Something like `/news?type=sports&area=chicago` -- what would I do then?

I know I must be missing something obvious here.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should be using the URI though, as a route parameter, instead of having it through GET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do it using a `foreach` loop, for example

```
$input = Input::all();
```

So, you'll get something like this (you should check `$input` is not null)

```
Array
(
    [type] => sports
    [area] => chicago
)
```

Now, select the table like

```
$events = DB::table('news');
```

Now `loop` the `$input` like (for multiple dynamic `where` clause)

```
foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
    $events->where($key, $value);
}
$result = $users->get();
```

Or you can use `orderBy` like (for multiple dynamic `orderBy` clause)

```
$events = DB::table('news')->where('category', $input['type']);
foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
    $events->orderBy($key); // also, you can use ASC/DESC as second argument 
}
$result = $users->get();
```

or you can use

```
$result = $users->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Thanks, 'breaking the chain' was the way to go.  I didnt end up using your loop, but you put me in the right direction.

Comment: @Jay, You are welcome and don't forget to share better ideas with the community, sharing makes things better. :-)